# Import JSON in PHP to EXCEL

Tags: php, json, excel

As the title suggests, I need to import specific values from JSON in PHP to EXCEL.

So I have my json data retrieved from a token in a php:

```
    $url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?api_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $object = json_decode($response, true);

foreach ($object['data'] as $key => $value){
echo $value['title'];
```

Now I want to use the **$value['title']** to be imported in excel.

I'm using PHPExcel, but I just don't know how to do it at all. Please help me.

Comment: Kindly look into this https://gist.github.com/nfeldman/1432857

Comment: You are doing fine. Just see some examples and start working :)

Comment: Perhaps reading some of the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md) or looking at some of the [PHPExcel Examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/01simple.php) will help

Comment: @SyedNoman - looking at that example, wondering why a home-rolled `getColLetter()` function when PHPExcel has a built-in `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()` method to do exactly that

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need complex features (for example, create an excel file with multiple sheets), you don't need to use PHPExcel, but you can simply modify the http header with:

```
$filename="sheet.xls";
header ("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header ("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
```

And then echo a table containing the data you want to display (you can also add basic style, as borders or backgrounds).